# Counting words in a map: the largest number is not incremented

Tags: java

I am making a word cloud program in Java and currently am stuck with counting the words. I am not allowed to use libraries such as kennykumo or opencloud that do most of it for me.

The user inputs a wall of text, I have taken out the stop words and put the result in an `ArrayList`. I am then searching for occurrences which works, every time it finds a repeated word it adds it to the map but it contains every single count and I need the highest count. Is it a loop to find the highest for each word?

Once I am able to get the number of occurrences against the word I can move on to assigning it the biggest font and then the next biggest and so on and displaying it for the user to see.

here is the code from the picture with some solutions I have tried commented out.

```
ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String word : arList) {
    if (!stopWordList.contains(word)) {
        wordsList.add(word);
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(wordsList, word);

        //System.out.println(word +" "+ occurrences);

        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        //HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(occurrences, word);

        //Map<String, Long> counts = wordsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(map);
        //map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Count : " + k + " word : " + v));
        Map<Integer, String> map2 = new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());
        map2.putAll(map);
     }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the issues found in the current implementation:

1. It is not effective because of re-counting every word using the `Collections.frequency()` method call.
2. It is not correct: the increment mechanism.

---

Please consider the following **draft** implementation (see the comments inline) to find and understand how you may correct and improve your original implementation (with stop words, etc.):

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Input.
        final List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "World",
            "World",
            "Goodbye"
        );

        // Output.
        // Associative container: maps a word to its count.
        final HashMap<String, Integer> wordToCountMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (final String word : words) {
            // Lookup into the map for the existing word counter.
            // If the word counter has not been found (we have just met the word for the first time),
            // create a counter with initial value.
            Integer wordCounter = wordToCountMap.getOrDefault(word, 0);

            // In any case, increase the counter and update the map with it.
            ++wordCounter;
            wordToCountMap.put(word, wordCounter);
        }

        // Output.
        // Preparing the output.
        final ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> highToLowCountEntries =
            new ArrayList<>(wordToCountMap.entrySet());
        // Sorting the collected entries by word count.
        Collections.sort(
            highToLowCountEntries,
            Comparator
                .comparing(AbstractMap.Entry<String, Integer>::getValue)
                .reversed()
        );

        System.out.printf("Entries: from high to low count: %s.%n", highToLowCountEntries);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented the stop word loop into it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @JakeFishlock, my pleasure! Glad it has helped you!